Compact symmetric space whose isometry group and isotropy group have the same rank?
I have trouble with understanding the proof of Theorem 8.6.7 of Wolf's Spaces of Constant Curvature, which conerns the Euler characteristic of a compact symmetric space:
In the theorem, $\textbf{I}_0(M)$ deontes the identity component of full isometry group and $K$ is the isotropy group in $\textbf{I}_0(M)$. Ranks are defined to be the dimension of the maximal torus in a compact Lie group.
In the last paragraph, he deduces that $ad(s)$ is an inner automorphism of $G$ directly from the assumption that $\text{rank}G=\text{rank}K$. Is this trivial to see? I have no idea how he can claim this. Any hints or ideas will be appreciated.
